# How can Gnosis Safe give allowance to a smart contract to spend specific token funds?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm wondering how can we use a Gnosis safe, to approve allowance to a specific smart contract, so it can execute transferFrom to operate the funds inside the safe.

Thanks

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: No, I didn't. I worked around with another solution. @Inn0vative1